# sp_msforeach db - Why do we need to use the USE keyword

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

`sp_msforeachdb` is an undocumented sp which is designed to run some T-SQL against every database in the server instance. Why then, does it appear that I need to use the `USE` keyword to do that

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDb @command1 = 'SELECT DB_NAME()'
```

Prints the database name the `sp_MSForEachDb` command was run against *n* times, where *n* is the number of databases on the instance.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDb @command1 = 'USE ?; SELECT DB_NAME()'
```

Prints the name of each database.

Why is it necessary to use the `USE` statement? Shouldn't this behavior be inherent in the procedure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The procedure does not perform a `USE` command for you. The way the procedure works is that it replaces every `?` in your command with the database prefix.

If you run this:

```
USE foodb;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb N'SELECT * FROM sys.objects;'; 
-- 3,380 total rows on my system
```

You will also get a number of resultsets that all show the objects from `foodb`. You have to issue the command this way in order to get the command to execute in the context of each individual database:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb N'SELECT * FROM ?.sys.objects;'; 
-- 50,603 total rows on my system
```

In this case it will execute your command for each database, with the `?` replaced by the database name:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.objects;
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.objects;
...
```

To call a system function that doesn't support a database prefix typically requires a `USE` command first. A way to do this differently could be:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb N'SELECT DB_NAME(DB_ID(''?''));';
```

Or, more simply:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb N'SELECT N''?'';';
```

One reason it works this way is that you might be executing from the context of the current database because it has a static object you want to use in relation to all of the databases. So, imagine you are in `foodb` and you create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ObjectNameBlacklist
(
  name sysname
);

INSERT dbo.ObjectNameBlacklist(name) VALUES('badword');
```

You want to identify all the objects in any database that match the names in this table. So you can say:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb N'SELECT ''?'', name 
  FROM dbo.ObjectNameBlacklist AS onb
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM ?.sys.objects WHERE name = onb.name
  );';
```

You wouldn't want the command to look for `dbo.ObjectNameBlacklist` in each database. Of course you could prefix that one manually, but you don't have to because of the way the procedure works.

Comment: And here is another example with Use :) to execute the same sql statements on every databases but system DBs:
http://www.oracle-scripts.net/sql-server-loop-through-databases/

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the `sp_helptext` entry for `sp_MSforeachdb`, or its weird friend `sp_MSforeachtable`

```
EXEC sys.sp_helptext @objname = N'sp_MSforeachdb';
EXEC sys.sp_helptext @objname = N'sp_MSforeachtable';
```

You'll see they're both just wrappers for `sp_MSforeach_worker`:

```
EXEC sys.sp_helptext @objname = N'sp_MSforeach_worker';
```

All they do is build up a valid `<list of things>`, but they don't actually loop over them in a meaningful way.

At any rate, [Aaron Bertrand's](https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp_msforeachdb) `sp_foreachdb` is a much better piece of code that doesn't skip databases, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `sp_helptext` for the procedure, you will see that it creates a cursor with databases' names and then runs `sp_MSforeach_worker`.
Comment from `sp_MSforeach_worker`:

> This is the worker proc for all of the "for each" type procs.  Its
>   function is to read the   next replacement name from the cursor (which
>   returns only a single name), plug it into the   replacement locations
>   for the commands, and execute them.  It assumes the cursor
>   "hCForEach***"   has already been opened by its caller.   worker_type
>   is a parameter that indicates whether we call this for a database (1)
>   or for a table (0)

So, `sp_msforeachdb` doesn't run a query on each database but runs a query with replaced '?' with database name for each database from `master.dbo.sysdatabases`.